# Download Mountain Lion on unsupported Mac?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Can I buy and download OS X 10.8, Mountain Lion, via the Mac App Store on an unsupported Mac?

My home internet is dial-up, so whenever I need to download stuff I go to the library with my Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6) MacBook.

For Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8), it doesn't work, because my MacBook isn't supported by Mountain Lion, even though I actually want to install 10.8 on my iMac at home, so the app store won't let me buy it.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Eric, 'Snow Leopard' is 10.6. 'Lion' is 10.7. Which do you have? Likely the App Store program looks at a particular string somewhere on your system to judge whether it can _run_ or not. If the string/file that the App Store checks is easily editable then you could spoof the download at least. However, this isn't necessarily even how it does. One way might be install [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) and look at which file is 'touched' by the App Store or someother process. Maybe even a log file (readable with the built-in Console app) can tell us?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use file [linked here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=18514232&postcount=994) to download mavericks, just use "Disk Utility" to restore the ".dmg" to a usb thumb drive then boot your mac off it, then select your hard drive and then let it finish booting.

I used this to download Mavericks on a late 2006 model Mac mini with 2GB of RAM. Mavericks won't install or run on it, but I was able to use the downloaded app along with tools from the "tonymacx86.com" website to make a USB installer to install on a PC to make a customac (aka a hackintosh)

I wish they still had Mountain Lion available to download, If they still did I think this method would have also worked to download it too.